Firemonkey high DPI form scale doesn't change when form location is changed
I have a c++ Firemonkey application which has a main form and 1, 2 or 3 graphics forms which are borderless with a TViewPort3D on them.
The application form displays on the main screen and the graphics forms display full screen size onto other screens.  The screen for displaying my graphics forms on is configurable, so I can change screen number and then via code, move that form to fill the selected screen.
When I enable DPI awareness (Per Monitor V2) I find that if any of my graphics forms is first displayed on the main screen, it will have that screens scale, even if I then move the form by code to another screen. The same happens if I first display it onto another screen by mistake and then change the screen number to display on, it retains the original screen scale value.
For example I have screen 1 - 250% scale high resolution, Screen 2 - 100% scale 1920 x 1080, Screen 3 100% scale 1920 x 1080.  If I display the form on Screen 1 and then move it to Screen 2 or Screen 3, it will have 250% scaling, even though it is now located on a screen with 100% scaling.
I am moving the screen in code by selecting a screen number, locating the coordinates of the screen I want in Screens class and setting the form to this new location and size so it fills the desired screen.  This all works, but images scale incorrectly as they have the wrong scale information. My 3D layout is resized when I move and resize the form, as is any background image.
Is there any mechanism for me to let the form know that it is on a new screen and should refresh its scale information?

Interesting observation, if I display the form first on one of the 100% screens, then display it on the 250% screen, it correctly fills the screen each time, but if I move it back to one of the 100% screens, it seems to retain the scale / size of the 250% screen.

I have confirmed this is a repeatable bug in FireMonkey form scaling when a form is moved in code and I have managed to find a workaround so the form correctly gets the screen scaling.
My work around is first moving the screen to the location I want by setting Top and Left to my desired screen and then toggling the property of the FireMonkey form "FullScreen" to true and then back to false.
if ((CurrentScreen >= 0)  && (CurrentScreen <= Screen->DisplayCount))
{
    TRectF FormBounds = Screen->Displays[CurrentScreen - 1].Bounds;      
    Width  = 100;
    Height = 100;
    Top    = FormBounds.top;
    Left   = FormBounds.left;
    FullScreen = true;
    FullScreen  = false;
    Show();
    SetBoundsF(FormBounds);
}

After I have done this, setting the bounds of the form to the size I actually want, works on the new screen.  I can move the form between screens and get reliable scale and sizing on the destination screen.
